# What's the size of a hashmap? When do I assign it?

Tags: java, hashmap

For an assignement I need to work with hashmaps, and I would like to ask a couple of questions:

1. Do Hashmaps have a fixed size like an array?
2. Are they like lists, where you can always add a new item to the hashmap?
3. Do I need to assign a size when I create a new hashmap?

Comment: No. Yes. No. See [documentation for HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: It is a collection framework like List. it doesn't have a fixed size. all you have to do is initialize and add items.

Comment: 3. No, but if you copy an existing map into it when you construct it, that's going to be  more efficient than adding the elements one-by-one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [`HashMap Documenation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

And so :

1. No, there is no fixed size
2. Yes, you can add as many element as you want, until you reach the max memory
3. No, but you can't give a initial capacity, in case you'd like to add a huge amount of data, this will allow the map to not extend itself a lot of time

The 2 keys of a `HashMap` are:

- The `capacity` is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created
  (`DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16`)
- The `load factor` is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is **automatically increased**. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is **rehashed** (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately **twice** the number of buckets. (`DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f`
  )